# How to find a Direct Proof given 3 integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I'm taking a discrete math course that's part of my major, and I've come across a question that has me stumped:

> Give a direct proof:
>
> Let a, b, and c be integers. If a|b and a|c, then a|(b * c).
>
> Remember that you must use the definition of | in your proof.

I understand | represents division. However, Relating to what the question is asking for I just don't know how to start this process. If someone could please walk me through this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you know what $a\mid b$ *really* means though? Obviously it means $a$ divides $b$, but what does *this* mean? That is, how would you represent it as an equation?

Comment: Are you sure it is not "or" vs. "and", i.e. $\, a\mid b\,$ or $\,a\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid bc.\ $ Otherwise $\,a\mid c\,$ is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $a\mid b$, then, by definition, we have that $b=\ell a$ for some $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$. Also, if $a\mid c$, then, by definition, we have that $c=\eta a$ for some $\eta\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now use this information effectively:
$$
b\cdot c = (\ell a)\cdot (\eta a) = a(a\eta\ell)=a\gamma,
$$
where $\gamma\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, by definition, we can see that $a\mid bc$ if $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$.

Comment: He wanted to know how to start, he didn't want you to do it for him...

Comment: This is a lot like proving an odd number is of the form 2p+1

Comment: @GFauxPas He asked for someone to "walk him through it"--that is what I did.

Comment: Thank you. Can I follow the same logic to prove that if  a|b and b|c, that a|c?

Comment: @TheAtomicPeter It is encouraged that you ask a new question as a new question, but the answer to your question is yes (if you cannot see how, then you may want to consider asking another question).

Answer (score 1):

First consider the information you are given.

By definition we have that if $a/b$ then $b=ak$ for some integer k.
If $a/c$ then $c=al$ for some integer l.

What information does this give us about bc?

What we can do is rewrite their product using the information and definitions to obtain $bc=akal=a^2kl$.

What does this tell us about what we're trying to prove?

We want to show that $a/bc$ which by definition means that $bc=aj$ for some integer j.

Looking at $bc=a^2kl$ we can see that allowing $j=akl$ we obtain $bc=aj$.

Given that $bc$ is a multiple of $a$ by definition we must have that $a/bc$.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bar does not denote division. It denotes divisibility.

A number $a$ divides a number $b$ iff $b = at$ for some integer $t$. This is denoted $a \mid b$.

Use this definition to put the $\text{if}$ part of your theorem into something you can manipulate into the $\text{then}$ part.